# Deploying Active/Standby ASA 5508-X pair - Need SMARTnet on both?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

I'm planning a deployment of a pair of Cisco ASA 5508-X firewalls in my co-location facility. I purchased the first unit with SMARTnet since it's a newer product and I wanted to get used to the configuration and feature set.

I'm closer to project deployment time and need to obtain the second unit.

Does the SMARTnet cover both units in an Active/Standby scenario? If not, should I buy coverage for the second firewall?

Comment: I just asked a former colleague, and at one time we purchased two 5515-X (iirc) and had to have a contract on each device. It's better to have both protected anyways.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need SMARTnet on both units if you want support as it is tied to the hardware serial number of the unit it covers. I highly recommend buying the coverage for both, especially if you've never setup failover.

Comment: You bought two devices; you need to contracts. The days of the Pix "failover bundle" are long gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need SmartNet on each individual unit (as the others have said, it's based on the unit's serial number) but if you want to save money, consider 8x5xNBD instead of the 24x7 option - since you now have a HA pair!  If you're desperate to save dollars, you can even ask your vendor for "RFR" = Return For Repair ... but ask about the difference in turnaround speed in repairs before committing to that.